# Debian Stretch - where did start-stop-daemon go, and how do I get it back?

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg, start-stop-daemon

I'm trying to recover from a faulty installation, and want to remove some packages. But I can't.

```
# apt autoremove offending-package
dpkg: warning:  'start-stop-daemon' not found in PATH or not executable
```

(My PATH is fine.)

According to packages.debian.org, start-stop-daemon should be in `/sbin/`.

It isn't there! What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way to do this is first create a dummy `/usr/local/sbin/start-stop-daemon` that does nothing:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec true
```

then simply reinstall [the dpkg package](https://packages.debian.org/sid/dpkg):

```
aptitude reinstall dpkg
```

then (of course) remove the dummy `/usr/local/sbin/start-stop-daemon`.

Installing the dpkg package does not in fact require `start-stop-daemon` at any point.  It is simply the case that the `dpkg` command, that is run to reinstall its own package, checks that `start-stop-daemon` is on the command search path *in case* a package installation/deinstallation script happens to use it.

Answer (score 5):

My solution was to download the  `dpkg`  binary and install  `start-stop-daemon`  by hand.

```
# apt download dpkg

# sudo ar -x dpkg_version-info.deb

# tar -xzf data.tar.gz

# mv ./sbin/start-stop-daemon /sbin
```

Now everything works, but I'm still stumped how it went missing!

Comment: @dirkt please explain the evidence that makes you guess that systemd blindly deleted files which belong to the dpkg package.

Comment: @dirkt that’s blatant FUD. `start-stop-daemon` is part of `dpkg`, no package, systemd-related or not, could cause its removal. You can also use `sysvinit` on Debian 9 if you don’t like systemd, no need to switch to Devuan (but anyone wishing to do so is of course welcome to).

Comment: In the future, use `dpkg-deb --extract dpkg_version-info.deb /tmp/dpkg` to extract the files into /tmp/dpkg

Comment: It worked great for me. Note: in 2020, ver. 10/Buster, archives are .xz not .gz files, but after extracting it works. Must set to executable in order to "fool" apt.

Comment: It worked for recover start-stop-daemon and ldconfig(from libc-bin) debian 11/Bullseye rescue.